# What is the reason of frameloss in case of high throughput in wlan?

Tags: wifi, corewlan, 802.11p

### Background:

I've implemented QoS with four queues having strict priorities in wireless device. Queue-0 is having highest priority , Queue-1 is second highest and so on. My wireless device was set as 20Mhz and MCS: -1 which gives throughput around 40-45mbps. 
 I tested this with JDSU having 8 streams of 10mbps that means total JDSU tx rate: 80mbps. In my overnight test, i found frame loss happened in queue-0 and queue-1 which was not expected if we place the device in RF chamber ( Lab environment).  
 However, If i limit the tx rate of JDSU within 45mbps then i don't find any frame loss.
Is there any relationship between throughput and frame loss? 
 My topology is like :

**jdsu**<---->**wifi master**<------air i/f------>**wifi slave >loopback**

Answer (score 1):

Just my two cents. Have you considered that the rate you are transmitting at is nearly double the supported data rate of your receiving devices? Wireless nodes broadcast their supported data rate for good reason. This is so other devices on the network can speak at a rate that the other device can understand. So I would say the answer to your question is an emphatic yes. Imagine if I were only capable of comprehending 1000 words per minute but you spoke at a rate of 2500 words per minute. You can safely expect that at some point I am going to be unable to comprehend every word that you are saying.

Comment: You are right !! However, it should not drop any packet from Queue-0 and Queue-1 as these are strict priority queues. I don't have any problem if it drops packets for queue-2 and queue-3.